# Почему сортировка при случайном порядке данных дольше чем при порядке по убыванию?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Не понимаю, почему данные расположенные в массиве в случайном порядке сортируются по возрастанию **дольше** (в разы дольше) чем при порядке по убыванию?

[image: Для наглядности]

Comment: Зависит от алгоритма, как вы сортируете данные?

Comment: Алгоритм Шелла. Сортировка во всех случаях по возрастанию. На вход даются данные в случайном порядке и сортируются. Затем отсортированный по возрастанию массив инвертируется (т.е. данные упорядочиваются по убыванию) и сортируется опять же по возрастанию.
В итоге данные расположенные в массиве в случайном порядке сортируются по возрастанию дольше чем при порядке по убыванию.

Comment: Код и метод его измерения в студию

Comment: @tym32167 код написан на PascalABC.NET https://pastebin.com/wUfv0HMC

Comment: @Vadik ответил на Ваш вопрос

Comment: не надо никаких ссылок никуда, добавляйте всю нужную инфомацию в вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 "превышение допустимой длины на 4502 символа"

Comment: у вас [сортировка Шелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)  занимает  4к+ символов? Тогда у вас что то не так с алгоритмом скорее всего.

Comment: @АнатолийЛиндеманн В **вопрос**, не в комментарий!

Comment: @tym32167 там целый "проект". Если я скину алгоритм Шелла (скопированный с интернета) это что-то даст? Замер времени Stopwatch.Start (сортировка Шелла) Stopwatch.Stop Stopwatch.Elapsed Stopwatch.Reset. Это всё что я использую для замера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внутри сортировки Шелла по выборкам должна использоваться сортировка вставками.

Последняя является адаптивной - т.е. для уже сортированных данных она выполняет меньше операций, чем для случайных. Поэтому на сортированном наборе работать как вставки, так и Шелл должны быстрее.

Надо заметить, что у вас вместо вставок используется какая-то экзотика, похожая не то на пузырёк, не то на гномью сортировку. Последние тоже являются адаптивными, и на сортированных данных будут быстрее.

Указанные вложенные сортировки сортируют убывающий массив долго, однако для сортировки Шелла характерно то, что упорядочение выборок очень быстро приводит к тому, что элементы быстро приходят близко к своей финальной позиции, а для таких массивов скорость вставок и пр. очень хорошая. Полный анализ сортировки Шелла, насколько я знаю, до сих пор не сделан.

К адаптивным сортировкам относятся также natural merge sort (не обычно применяемый вариант), Timsort. А практически не зависят от упорядоченности данных сортировка выбором, быстрая, кучей.

Ещё у вас используется не слишком хорошая последовательность размеров шагов с делением их пополам. Да, дедушка Шелл так делал (у него были степени двойки), но с тех пор показали, что правильный выбор шагов существенно влияет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение. Если резюмировать написанное Вами, получается это нормально, что сортировка случайно расположенных данных занимает больше времени?

Comment: Да, для данного алгоритма.