# Почему скорость сортировки данных упорядоченных по убыванию и возрастанию практически одинаковая?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, pascal

Пытаюсь разобраться в **пирамидальной** сортировке. Почему данные расположенные в массиве по убыванию сортируются по возрастанию практически с такой же скоростью как и данные расположенные в массиве по возрастанию? ***При пирамидальной сортировке***

Код программы:
Код используемой пирамидальной сортировки (взял с методички у преподавателя)

```
program s;
CONST N=1000000;
TYPE MAS = ARRAY[1..N] OF Real;
VAR A:MAS;
var i,j,first,last:integer;

procedure vvod(var A:MAS);
var M:integer;
begin
  writeln;
  write('Введи М: ');
  readln(M);
  for var i:=1 to N do
    A[i]:=Random(M);
end;

procedure vivod(var A:MAS);
begin
for var i:=1 to N do
  write(A[i]:5)
end;

procedure Heapsort (var A:MAS);
var k:integer;
x:real;
flag: boolean;
begin
  for var i:=(N div 2) downto 1 do
  begin
    j:=i;
    while j<=(N div 2) do
    begin
      k:=2*j;
      if (k+1<=N) and (A[k]<A[k+1]) then
        k:=k+1;
      if A[k]>A[j] then
      begin
        x:=A[j];
        A[j]:=A[k];
        A[k]:=x;
        j:=k;
      end
      else
        break;
    end;
  end;
  for var i:=N downto 2 do
  begin
    x:=A[1];
    A[1]:=A[i];
    A[i]:=x;
    j:=1;
    flag:=true;
    while (j<=((i-1) div 2)) and flag do
    begin
      k:=2*j;
      if (k+1<=i-1) and (A[k]<A[k+1]) then
        k:=k+1;
      if A[k]>A[j] then
      begin
        x:=A[j];
        A[j]:=A[k];
        A[k]:=x;
        j:=k;
      end
      else
        flag:=false
    end
  end;
end;

var stopw := new Stopwatch;
begin
  vvod(A);
  writeln('Исходный массив');
 // vivod(A);
  writeln();
  writeln;
  writeln('Сортировка методом пирамиды (случайное заполнение)');
  stopw.start;
  Heapsort(A);
  stopw.Stop;
  writeln(stopw.Elapsed.Ticks/10000:0:2);
  stopw.Reset;
  writeln;
  writeln('Отсортированный массив');
 // vivod(A);
 writeln;
  writeln;
  writeln('Сортировка методом пирамиды (заполнение по возрастанию)');
  stopw.start;
  Heapsort(A);
  stopw.Stop;
   writeln(stopw.Elapsed.Ticks/10000:0:2);
  stopw.Reset
end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хм... [Вот только что было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1313144/)

Сортировка кучей - не **адаптивная** (как и сортировка выбором, как и быстрая). Её скорость мало зависит от упорядоченности данных

При построении кучи - при придании массиву свойства двоичной кучи -  выполняется упорядочение снизу вверх. Если массив уже имеет свойства кучи (заметьте, что при этом он не так упорядочен, как массив по возрастанию или убыванию), то обменов не будет, но на асимптотику это не влияет. Этот этап занимает время O(n), он быстрее второго.

На втором этапе на каждом шаге выполняется обмен максимума с вершины кучи с последним текущим индексом. После этого бывший последний опускается с вершины, пока можно - этих шагов будет в пределах количества уровней log(n).

Вот и получается время O(nlogn) в целом.

Comment: А если данные в массив расположены в случайном порядке, то получится их сортировка всё равно будет дольше? Хоть и "скорость мало зависит от упорядоченности данных"

Comment: Время для случайного порядка должно быть примерно такое же. Первый этап, на котором это более-менее влияет, всё равно быстрее второго.

Comment: Странно, что у меня получается так, что при случайном заполнении сортировка занимает больше времени. Примерно (в среднем) в 1.5 раза больше

Comment: Как измеряете ?

Comment: Как-то так. https://codeshare.io/gL8jyN

Comment: для размера 100?????

Comment: Это я написал 100 чтобы много значений не выводилось в консоль. Чтобы проще было найти время выполнения.

Вообще, по данному мне заданию, нужно для размера 10000. Да я понимаю, что такая сортировки не используется в таких бредовых задачах, но это не я придумал такое задание :)

Comment: Измерять нужно на размерах порядка миллиона. Вывод отключить.

Comment: Да, при размере равном 1 миллиону сортировка при случайном заполнении занимает: 00:00:00.2965590. При заполнении по возрастанию 00:00:00.2086632. Теперь разница намного меньше чем была до этого, но тем не менее сортировка при случайном заполнении занимает больше времени

Comment: Ну посчитайте количество операций каждого вида на втором этапе, видимо, пути погружения (в вашей реализации погружение, а не подъём, исправлю в ответе) длиннее получаются для случайных, хотя умозрительно - это странно.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за подробное объяснение.